# How to solve the error "Not a valid XPath expression"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

In selenium on Java, im try to find an element and select it on a webpage but it keep getting the error:

```
The string '//*[@id='app']/article/div[2]/section/div[1]/div[5]/div/section[2]/div[2]/div[1]/' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

How can I get it at all??

Comment: you have an extra '/' at the end, remove it and it's fine.

Comment: Can't you select `div[1]` directly with CSS selector?

Comment: share the html for which you want to have xpath.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you are seeing an error as **not a valid XPath expression** because you have exactly 2 issues in it as follows:

- As you are passing the *xpath* within single quotes i.e. **`''`** you can't use the same for the *attribute values*.
- Ideally an *xpath* shouldn't end with a **`/`**
- So your effective *xpath* will be either of the following:

  ```
  '//*[@id="app"]/article/div[2]/section/div[1]/div[5]/div/section[2]/div[2]/div[1]'
  ```

  or

  ```
  "//*[@id='app']/article/div[2]/section/div[1]/div[5]/div/section[2]/div[2]/div[1]"
  ```

Comment: Based chad dev, you just solved my problem. upvoted sir.