# Getting parent item from child without Xpath

Tags: python, selenium, appium

I have a list of devices on my app screen. Each webelement that represents a unique device has 2 children:

- (unique) device name
- On/Off status

Parent devices have the same id, so the way to select the correct device is to go through the children and check that device_name.text is the name I want.

I'm trying to write a functions that evaluates on off status for a specific device name without using xpath

```
def check_on_off_status(device_name:WebElement):
   device = device_name.find_element_by_xpath('..') # we find the parent from device_name, and navigate from there
   # power_status_element =  get_child(device,power_status_id)
   # return power_status_element.enabled
```

But I'm getting an exception when evaluating the xpath expression. How can I get the parent node if I only have the element?

Edit:

**Parent (Device) Xpath**

/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout   /android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout   /android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup      /androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager   /androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.widget.FrameLayout   /android.view.ViewGroup/androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView   /android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout  /android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup

**Device Name Xpath:**
/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager/androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.TextView[1]

**On/Off Icon (device name sibling) Xpath:**

/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager/androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.ImageView

Comment: Can you share the HTML area screenshot in question, and if you can provide the URL so that we can help in better way.

Comment: @GauravLad what I'm looking for is a function that will output the parent element given a known child element for any given url, is that possible?

Comment: Can you help me understand why you don't what it with xpath?

Comment: @GauravLad because I'd like to use the same function in multiple screens of the app (which will get refactored in the future), if possible. Added the xpath of the relevant items in an edit, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You were close enough. You just need to append the `./` character within the [xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447) so the `..` can be referenced with respect to the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52805139/7429447) *`device_name`* as follows:

```
device = device_name.find_element_by_xpath('./..')
```

Comment: Changed to ' ./..'   ->selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.

Comment: @Joolz can you try once with `.//..`

Comment: same response as before

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based HTML please.

Comment: Added an edit with the relevant items, thanks!