# How can I make Selenium click on a href by css selector?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have been trying to make a Selenium bot that searches for a word on github, clicks on the first link and then downloads it with Python 3.8 and I got stuck with making the bot click on the hyperlink. I understand that I can make the bot click on it with `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "Xpath").click()` but I want to be able to find the path of the href with another method for the sake of learning, in this case CSS_SELECTOR. Source code of the first hyperlink result is like this:

HTML:

[image: source code]

Since every single result is under the same "a" selector with a class of "v-align-middle", I thought of using this code: `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".v-align-middle").click()` but it did not seem to work. What am I missing?

Comment: Which [_xpath_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447) worked for you?

Comment: The xpath that worked for me was "//*[@id='js-pjax-container']/div/div[3]/div/ul/li[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a"
which I gathered from copying the xpath from the part of the source code where href is included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired element is a dynamic element, so to `click()` on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.v-align-middle[href='/asdf-vm/asdf'][data-hydro-click][data-hydro-click-hmac]"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='v-align-middle' and @href='/asdf-vm/asdf'][@data-hydro-click and @data-hydro-click-hmac]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Although you stated that what I want to interact with is dynamic, isn't there a way that I can simply treat it as "the first result to show up" and use no specific code that involves "href='/asdf-vm/asdf'" because the part that comes after href= is going to change for every result.

Comment: Incase value of `href` attribute is dynamic, then you have to drop the attribute from the [_locator strategies_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over)

Comment: I have just managed to solve it the way I want. It seems that `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.v-align-middle").click()` works with the current version of Selenium instead of the one I was trying.