# How to find the correct xpath for the element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

HTML:

```
<div class="team" data-team="test-invite14">
    <div class="team-body"><span class="avatar xlarge no-image" style="background-color: rgb(223, 103, 255);">T</span>
    </div>
    <div class="team-foot">Test.invite14</div>
</div>
```

I have tried multiple times but didn't got positive response
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What element do you want to locate here? What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried XPath using choropath, Can you please help me to find the correct xpath ?

Comment: I'm asking: what element are you trying to locate here? There are 3 divs here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447) are as follows:

- *XPATH* for ***T***:

  ```
  //div[@class='team']/div[@class='team-body']/span[text()='T']
  ```
- *XPATH* for ***Test.invite14***:

  ```
  //div[@class='team']//div[@class='team-foot' and text()='Test.invite14']
  ```

Answer (score 0):

//div[@class='team']

//div[@data-team='test-invite14']

Use any one of this and try

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).