# How to click on SVG element in highcharts to download file using Selenium

Tags: selenium, svg, xpath, highcharts, webdriverwait

My first question was related to this. In the meantime I have found a less efficient workaround. I'd still like automatically download these files.

I would like my script to click on the download icon, click on the Download XLS icon that follows of the page below. The green arrow is where I'd like to click.

The id of the highchart changes every time the page loads. I've tried to fix it it with code sample:

```
def unityengine_data():
    driver.get("https://steamdb.info/tech/Engine/Unity/")
    wait
    WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "div[contains(@id,'highcharts-')]//*[local-name() = 'svg']/*[name()='g'][6]/*[name()='g']/*[name()='image']"))).click
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "div[contains(@id,'highcharts-')]//**[local-name() = 'div']/*[name()='ul'][6]/*[name()='li'][2]"))).click
    os.rename("downloaded file path", "new file path")
    return "Unity Engine apps data successfully downloaded"
```

Website image

[image: Website image]

Website after first click

[image: Website after first click]

I hope you can help.

Answer (score 1):

You are simply missing `//` here at this line

```
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "div[contains(@id,'highcharts-')]//*[local-name() = 'svg']/*[name()='g'][6]/*[name()='g']/*[name()='image']"))).click
```

also, you should ideally create object of `WebDriverWait` once and reuse it whenever you want.

See the below code, I have improved one locator as well.

**Code:**

```
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get("https://steamdb.info/tech/Engine/Unity/")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@id,'highcharts-')]//*[local-name() = 'svg']/*[name()='g'][6]/*[name()='g']/*[name()='image']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[text()='Download XLS']"))).click()
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. You just need three minor adjustments and one optimization as follows:

- You need to add the leading `//` for an effective xpath.
- [*click*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) is a method so you need to ***click()***
- The [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447) for the *highchart image* can be optimized a bit.
- The element with text ***Download XLS*** is within *`local-name`* space, hence you don't need `[local-name() = 'div']`

Your effective code block will be:

```
driver.get("https://steamdb.info/tech/Engine/Unity/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@id,'highcharts-')]//*[local-name() = 'svg']//*[name()='g']//*[name()='image']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='highcharts-menu']//li[text()='Download XLS']"))).click()
```

Browser Snapshot;

[image: highcharts]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to click on SVG elements using XPath and Selenium WebDriver through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41829000/7429447)