# WebElement cant be found with Xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, appium, appium-java

I **find** the element with By.id, as the following code:

```
element = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.id(
    "com.test:id/product_detail_nav_host"
));
```

But none of this lines can find the same element:

```
element = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath(
    "//*[id='com.test:id/product_detail_nav_host']"
));
```

```
element = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath(
    "//*[@id='com.test:id/product_detail_nav_host']"
));
```

```
element = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath(
    "//*[resource-id='com.test:id/product_detail_nav_host']"
));
```

Answer (score 1):

The first [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) is errorprone as you are missing the `@` before the keyword *`id`*

---

The third [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447) is also errorprone as the value

```
com.test:id/product_detail_nav_host
```

is of the ***id*** attribute, but not the ***resource-id*** attribute.

---

However, the second code block looks flawless to me and should work perfecto:

```
element = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath(
    "//*[@id='com.test:id/product_detail_nav_host']"
));
```