# How to identify an element with no innerText using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, innertext

I have an element that looks like this:

```html
<td style="font-weight: bold; text-align:right;"></td>
```

Is there anyway to change or detect the blank value between the tags in selenium python?

P/S: This is just an example. There are many elements like this in the data I'm working with.

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML:

```
<td style="font-weight: bold; text-align:right;"></td>
```

the `<td>` element doesn't have any *`text`* or *`innerText`* and in that case you can identify the `<td>` element as using the following [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447):

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[not(text())]"));
```

However, you have to take help of additional attributes so the [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over) identify the element uniquely within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).