# How to click through multiple elements with same XPATH in selenium using for loop?

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, web-scraping

I'm trying to web scrape different elements with same class name. The following statements works well.

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[@class= 'jumbo-tracker'])[1]").click()
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[@class= 'jumbo-tracker'])[2]").click()
```

...
and so on.

Now, if I put this in a loop, it doesn't work. Looks like, it doesn't recognize (//div[@class= 'jumbo-tracker'])[i]

Here's the code:

```
for i in range(1,length+1):
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[@class= 'jumbo-tracker'])[i]").click()
    sleep(5)
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='sc-1y3q50z-3 eiMLBn']").click()
    sleep(5)
    sno.append(restaurant)
    restaurant_name= browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//h1[contains(@class, 'sc-7kepeu-0 sc-kafWEX kTxZkY')]").text
    name.append(restaurant_name)
    browser.back()
    browser.back()
    sleep(5)
```

Here's the exception:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//div[@class= 'jumbo-tracker'])[i]"}
```

Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### range()

The [`range()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp) function creates a sequence of numbers.

So while passing the variable within the [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447) using [f-strings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/) you need to convert the *`number`* as ***`string`*** for variable substitution and you can use the following line of code:

```
for i in range(1,length+1):
        browser.find_element(By.XPATH, f"(//div[@class= 'jumbo-tracker'])[{str(i)}]").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can click all elements keep in for loop and you have to use elements instead of element.

```
clicks = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class= 'jumbo-tracker']")

for click in clicks:
   click = click.click()
   time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use string interpolation. String interpolation is a process substituting values of variables into placeholders in a string. This example (based on your code) uses an f-string:

```
for i in range(1,length+1):
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH, f"(//div[@class= 'jumbo-tracker'])[{i}]").click()
```