# How to traverse back to the parent of an element in Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

i have this element

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '/cargas')]")
```

that search text in html and select one element
suppose the element has the xpath

```
//*[@id="main"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[11]
```

is there a way to return div's in this element eg:

```
element cd.. cd..

//*[@id="main"]/div[3]/div/div[2]
```

and how i get the full xpath from element

Comment: You want to return to a web element on what basis ?

Comment: to for exemple click on edit button in a chat menseger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the way in *MS DOS* [os](/questions/tagged/os) you traverse back to the parent directory using `cd..`, using [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447) you can move to the parent element as follows:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '/cargas')]")
parent_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '/cargas')]/..")
grand_parent_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '/cargas')]/../..")
```