# Selenium doesn't find element by CssSelector

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="StyledButton-sc-323bzc-0 heNFVr" style="width: auto;"><div tabindex="0" class="StyledBox-sc-13pk1d4-0 bPuLmq secondary-btn null"><span class="StyledText-sc-1sadyjn-0 gacBiv" style="letter-spacing: 0.1em;">TRANSFER</span></div></button>
```

Code trials:

```
transfer_input = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR,value= '//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[5]/button')
transfer_input.click()
```

Snapshot of the error:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/znLPJ.png]

I tried do by Xpath, or class name it still doesn't find.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things as follows:

- You have mentioned about using `by=By.CSS_SELECTOR` but the value was of [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447).
- Instead of a *absolute xpath* you can construct a *relative xpath*.
- Ideally to click on a **clickable** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='button'] > div[class*='secondary-btn'] > span"))).click()
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button/div[contains(@class, 'secondary-btn')]/span[@class and text()='TRANSFER']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a XPath, not a CSS Selector. Try these one of these three options.

```
transfer_input = wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[5]/button')
    )
)
transfer_input.click()
```

OR

```
transfer_input = wait.until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[5]/button')
    )
)
transfer_input.click()
```

OR

```
import time
time.sleep(10) # sleep for 10 seconds
transfer_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[5]/button')
transfer_input.click()
```