# Selenium C#: How to identify element without particular child element

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, findelement

I have following elements on the page:

```
<span class="card-body">
    <span>No tickets</span>
    <h5 class="card-title">..</h5>
    <p class="card-text card-text-top">..</p>
    <p class="card-text">..</p>
</span>
```

There are several the same `card-body` elements in the DOM, however, I would like to identify the first one that **does not** contain `<span>No tickets</span>` child element.

What is the most correct locator which I should use, while working with selenium and C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To identify the first element that does not have a decendent `<span>No tickets</span>` element you can use the following [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447) based [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

```
//span[@class='card-body'][not(.//span[text()='No tickets'])]
```

Your effective line of code will be:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='card-body'][not(.//span[text()='No tickets'])]"))
```

Snapshot of the example:

[image: ticket]

Comment: Unfortunately not. 
However, i figured out, that following xpath works fine:
`//*[contains(@class, 'card-body') and not(span[text()='No tickets'])]`

Comment: Check the snapshot as a proof for the logic

Answer (score 0):

```
//span[@class='card-body'][not(span[text()='No tickets'])]
```

Gets the span with class `card-body` that does not have span with text "No tickets".