# Selenium only finding some, but not all, related elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm attempting to use Selenium to print out a list of users I'm subscribed to on a website, of which there are 3. The following code only prints out the first 2 of the three

```
from xml.dom.minidom import Element
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import wait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService;
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager;
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.actions.action_builder import ActionBuilder
from selenium.webdriver.common.actions.mouse_button import MouseButton
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()));
#Chrome client should now start up


driver.get("website-url"); #Go to desired website
title = driver.title;
if title == "WebsiteTitle":
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

email_box = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "email"); #finds username block
pass_box = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password"); #finds password block

email_box.send_keys('username'); #enter username
pass_box.send_keys('password'); #enter password

submit_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"); #finds submit button
submit_button.click(); #clicks it

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='content']/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/h1/span"))); #waits 15sec until the "Home" button on the home page can be clicked

def print_subs_list():          #function to print list of users you are subscribed to
    driver.get("website-subs-url");
    subscriptions_list = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='content']/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/a/div")
    for value in subscriptions_list:
        print(value.text)

print_subs_list()

driver.quit()
```

Now, changing the XPath in subscriptions_list to `//*[@id='content']/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/a/div` will print out the 3rd result only.
However, my desired result would be to print all of the subscribed users, as there will definitely be more than 3.
How do I change it so that it will print out all of the subscribed users, regardless of the amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You identify all the three desired elements using the [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447):

```
//*[@id='content']/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div//div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/a/div
```

Your effective line of code will be:

```
subscriptions_list = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='content']/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div//div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/a/div")
```

Comment: plugging that in will only print out the 3rd element, not all 3

Comment: Did you test that?

Comment: Ok you got me, it worked!
But how did replacing div[2] in the XPath with /div fix it? How does that identify all 3 elements?
Edit: Nvm, I just need to read up more on how to use Xpath

Comment: Glad to be able to help you. To consider both `div[1]` as well as `div[2]` I decided to go with `//div`