# Selenium: locator for the button field

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to write an automation script with Java and Selenium for this [site](https://www.openstreetmap.org/), but I got stuck while trying to find a locator for the directions button.

Locator:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//a[@href=\"/directions\"]")    
private WebElement directionsButton;
```

Methods:

```
public void clickOnDirectionsButton() {
        waitForElementAndClick(directionsButton);
    }
public void waitForElementAndClick(WebElement element) {
        getWebDriverWait().until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)).click();
    }

private WebDriverWait getWebDriverWait() {
        return new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), Duration.ofSeconds(5));
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-auto">
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary switch_link" title="Find the route" href="/directions"><img width="20" height="20" src="/assets/directions-6ae0ecdabcaa76d0d14dddddfa7d6381ecdd817b05f751ea422e53493945e942.png" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

When I launch the script, the browser is started, but then nothing is going on and the script ends with an exception as follows:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for frame to be available: [[ChromeDriver: chrome on MAC (4c996493878e66ee1e24eb2224a1175b)] -> xpath: //a[@href="/directions"]] (tried for 5 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
```

I want the script to click on the directions button. How can I achieve such behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447) based [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) which you have used:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//a[@href=\"/directions\"]")    
private WebElement directionsButton;
```

doesn't identifies the desired element uniquely within the HTML but identifies two elements:

[image: directions]

---

### Solution

To identify the element uniquely you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  @FindBy(css = "div#content a[title='Find directions between two points'][href='/directions']")    
  private WebElement directionsButton;
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@id='content']//a[@title='Find directions between two points' and @href='/directions']")    
  private WebElement directionsButton;
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 anchor nodes with the same `@href="/directions"`. The first one is hidden. Try to use this XPath:

```
//a[@title='Find directions between two points']
```