# IsDisplayed() throwing me NoSuchElementException error instead of printing boolean value

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, error-handling

We have `IsDisplayed()` method created in our framework at `lib` class:

```
public static boolean isDisplayed()(WebElement locator){

try{
return locator.isDisplayed();
}catch (Exception e){
return false;
}
}
```

This is the WebElement:

```
public WebElement icon(String rootnumber){
WebElement e=driver.findElement.(By.xpath("//div[@row_id='"+rootnumber+"']//following-sibling::span[@matbadgecolor='warn']"));
return e;
}
```

So inside a method, I tried to print boolean value of icon like this:

```
System.out.println("Boolean value of icon presence is "+lib.isDisplayed(icon("123456789")));
```

It gives me  `NoSuchElementException` error at this `sysout` command instead of printing boolean value.

Comment: It's the `icon`, not the `isDisplayed`, that throws that.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. But while dealing with [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447) the function is [**`following-sibling()`**](https://www.guru99.com/using-contains-sbiling-ancestor-to-find-element-in-selenium.html).

So you just need to replace `foolowing-sibling` with *`following-sibling`* and your effective code block will be:

```
public WebElement icon(String rootnumber){
WebElement e=driver.find(By.xpath("//div[@row_id='"+rootnumber+"']//following-sibling::span[@matbadgecolor='warn']"));
return e;
}
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based HTML.

Comment: That is **typo** while posting question here. I entered "following" still throwing same error.