# Python Selenium-BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

```
paths = ['/html/body/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/section/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/a/h3',
'/html/body/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/section/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/a/h3',
'/html/body/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/section/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[1]/a/h3',]
```

```
urls = []
for path in paths:
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, path)
    url = element.get_attribute('href')
    urls.append(url)
    element.click()
    driver.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    element = soup.find('p')
    if element:
        element_text = element.get_text()
        print(element_text)
    else:
        print(f"No p tag found in {url}")
```

```
driver.get(url)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 455, in get
self.execute(Command.GET, {"url": url})
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 444, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'url' must be a string
```

This is the problem. How can I fix it

Comment: What is `url`.  Did you verify that you were able to find something with the `find_element` and that what you found was an anchor that has an `href`?

Comment: Hi. https://www.huffpost.com/news/politics this is the url. My priority is to get the text that comes out after clicking the link in the path as a report.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [(unofficial) documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute), if the attribute is, for whatever reason (ex. wrong XPath, wrong attribute name, etc.), unable to get the attribute from the element, it returns None. None is not a string, it's a builtin type. That's most likely your issue.

> This method will first try to return the value of a property with the given name. If a property with that name doesn’t exist, it returns the value of the attribute with the same name. If there’s no attribute with that name, None is returned.

Answer (score 0):

The [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447):

```
/html/body/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/section/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/a/h3
```

refers to the `<h3>` element which doesn't have any ***`href`*** value. But ofcoarse the parent `<a>` tag have the ***`href`*** attribute set.

[image: h3]

So the values assigned to `url` was always *`NULL`* in each iteration:

```
url = element.get_attribute('href')
```

Hence you see the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'url' must be a string
```

---

### Solution

You need to move up to the parent `<a>` tag and extract the ***`href`*** attribute value and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
/html/body/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/section/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/a/h3//parent::a[1]
```