# How to write xpath for li content for breadcrumb items

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, xpath-1.0

I want to write an xpath for verify the ***Custom Report*** text without index.

HTML:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <a href="https://dumpy.url.com">Lw2_0702230135</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://dumpy.url.com">Report</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        Custom Report
    </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following xpath:

```html
//ol/li[contains(text(), "Custom Report")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <a href="https://dumpy.url.com">Lw2_0702230135</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://dumpy.url.com">Report</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        Custom Report
    </li>
</ol>
```

To identify the element with text ***Custom Report*** you can use the following [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447) based [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

```
//ol/li[last()]
```

Code (*Python*):

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//ol/li[last()]")
```