# find List Item based on known string

Tags: python, list, selenium-webdriver, invalidselectorexception

I'm playing around with [booking.com](https://www.booking.com/) as I teach myself selenium / python. I'm trying to select a currency based on a known string e.g. 'USD'.

I'm able to click the currency icon to open the currency selection modal but then when I try to say find element where text = 'USD', I get:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

**1. Here is the list item for 'USD':**

```
<li class="ccff2b4c43 ea27cffb06"><button data-testid="selection-item" type="button" class="fc63351294 ea925ef36a bf97d4018a ae8177da1f cddb75f1fd"><div class="a1b3f50dcd a1f3ecff04 b2fe1a41c3 db7f07f643 d19ba76520"><div class="b1e6dd8416 aacd9d0b0a"><span class="cf67405157">U.S. Dollar<div class=" ea1163d21f">USD</div></span></div><div class=""></div></div></button></li>
```

**2. Here is my known string I'm trying to search for:**

```
currency = 'USD'
```

**3. Here is my attempt at trying to find (then select) this string in the HTML:**

```
selected_currency_element = self.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'//span[text()={currency}]')
selected_currency_element.click()
```

I assume I don't need to read this modal's entire unordered list into an array then loop through it to find the string? Or do I?

Comment: Focus your search at the `<li>` tag, not the `<span>` tag. From there, you might find success doing a regex search for `"USD"` on the list items' `innerHTML` attribute in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things to rectify.

1. The used syntax is for `XPATH` and you have used `CSS_SELECTOR` need to change to `XPATH`

`selected_currency_element = self.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//span[text()={currency}]')`

2. If you see the node `USD` is inside a `DIV` tag of parent `SPAN`
   So your `xpath` should be like
   `selected_currency_element = self.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//span[.//div[text()="{currency}"]]')`

Comment: Thanks all for your help. This works well now, with KunduK's syntax being 100%. 

Please correct me if I misunderstand but my takeaway from your collective responses is that By.XPATH seems to be the preferred locator type for locating innerHTML within nested div / span elements. 

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the abbreviation, I used the long name.  This works pretty good. By the way, I use Firefox as my browser

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

def change_currenecy(country):
    
    dvr = webdriver.Firefox()
    dvr.get("https://www.booking.com/")
    dvr.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'USD')]")[0].click()
    dvr.find_elements(By.XPATH, f"//span[contains(text(),'{country}')]")[0].click()
    
    
change_currenecy("Thai Baht")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of a couple of things here:

- Though you mentioed `By.CSS_SELECTOR` but the value is of a [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447). So you need to change the [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) as:

  ```
  selected_currency_element = self.find_element(By.XPATH, f'xpath_value')
  ```
- The desired text ***USD*** is within the descendant `<div>` of  it's parent `<span>`, so you need to go a step deeper.

---

### Solution

Your effective line of code will be:

```
currency = 'USD'
selected_currency_element = self.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//span//div[text()={currency}]')
selected_currency_element.click()
```