# How to locate a date element using the xpath from the calendar

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I'm trying to locate the webelement for the future date but unable to do so. I am finding more than one matching web elements for the same.

I tried:

```
//*[contains(@class,'flatpickr-day nextMonthDay') and @aria-label='June 3, 2023']
```

and various other xpath but no luck.

Here is the snapshot of the HTML:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML:

[image: html]

To identify the date ***June 3, 2023*** the [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447) which you have used:

```
//*[contains(@class,'flatpickr-day nextMonthDay') and @aria-label='June 3, 2023']
```

have certain issues as follows:

- *Today* being ***June 2, 2023***, the day ***June 3, 2023*** won't contain the class *nextMonthDay*.
- Using contains clause it's better to pass a single attribute value.

---

### Solution

To locate the date ***June 3, 2023*** you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  span.flatpickr-day[aria-label^='June 3']
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  span.flatpickr-day[aria-label*='June 3']
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  //span[@class='flatpickr-day ' and starts-with(@aria-label, 'June 3')]
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  //span[@class='flatpickr-day ' and contains(@aria-label, 'June 3')]
  ```

Comment: I tried all for locators and it says there are "4 elements matching."

Comment: And when I ran my code I got an error:              
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of -> xpath: //span[@class='flatpickr-day ' and starts-with(@aria-label, 'June 6,')]] (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: Not sure but I am still unable to click on the date. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: @tester _it says there are "4 elements matching_: Possibly there are total 4 DatePicker fields with "June 6", so you need to uniquely identify the desired with "June 6" element from the 4 available datepickers.