# Selenium Python doesn't find element using path

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation

I am new to Selenium and I try to find what's wrong with my code. I think the problem is not with slow loading of page(it is very slow), but when the code is reaching `print('I am wating')` program is waiting 30 seconds and after that I am having the error `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:`. When it reaches this moment, there is no loading of the page or sth like that, it is just printing this information and after 30 seconds it gives these error. Code of my program is below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import os
import typing
import types


class BrowserOperator(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self, page_url, teardown: bool = False):
        self._teardown = teardown
        self._pageUrl = page_url
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        super(BrowserOperator, self).__init__(options=options)
        self.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.maximize_window()

def __exit__(self, exc_type: typing.Optional[typing.Type[BaseException]], exc: typing.Optional[BaseException], traceback: typing.Optional[types.TracebackType]):
    print(self._teardown)
    if self._teardown:
        print(self._teardown)
        self.quit()

def load_first_page(self):
    self.get(self._pageUrl)

def check_address_correctness(self):
    if self.current_url != self._pageUrl:
        return self.load_first_page()

def accept_cookies(self):
    print('I am wating')
    cookie_button = self.find_element(
        By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/button[2]')
    print(cookie_button)
    # cookie_button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe the xpath is not correct, you can use class_name etc...

I know a method to loate the absxpath by using edge

in the edge webpage, rightclick and click the **Inspect**, locate the element and rightclick and click  **Copy  Copy FULL XPATH**

the document
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/#find-elements-from-element

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'p')
fruits = driver.find_element(By.ID, "fruits")
plants = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a")
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are trying to invoke click on the [cookie](/questions/tagged/cookie) accept button. Using **absolute** [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447) makes your test execution ***flaky***. Instead you need to use **logical** xpaths. As an example:

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  button[attribute='attribute_value']
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  //button[@attribute='attribute_value']
  ```

PS: In the above examples, *`attribute`* and *`attribute_value`* are placeholders.

---

### Solution

Ideally, to locate and click on the **clickable** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[attribute='attribute_value']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@attribute='attribute_value']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [***NoSuchElementException***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47995294/7429447) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50315715/7429447)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53442511/7429447)