# Concatenate String with double quotes in Java

Tags: java, string, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-java

Now I have method, which will return me xpath value i.e.

```
public String xpathValue (String countryName){
return "//*[label="+countryName+"]"
}
```

And if I call it with Nigeria it will return me value like this:

```
//*[@label=Nigeria]
```

But I want value surrounded with double quotes, like this:

```
//*[@label="Nigeria"]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447) is:

```
//*[@label='Nigeria']
```

and to generate the above, you can use the following line of code:

```
return "//*[@label='"+countryName+"']";
```

and to generate:

```
//*[@label="Nigeria"]
```

You can use the following line of code:

```
return "//*[@label=\""+countryName+"\"]";
//                 ^the above backslash indicates that the following character i.e. " is printable
```

---

### POC

Code:

```
public class XPathStringDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        XPathStringDemo obj = new XPathStringDemo();
        System.out.println(obj.xpathValue("Nigeria"));

    }
    public String xpathValue (String countryName){
        return "//*[@label=\""+countryName+"\"]";
        }

}
```

Output:

```
//*[@label="Nigeria"]
```

Comment: Love this explanation of yours..